# C# Работа с файлами

Tags: c#, файлы

Есть класс студент в котором идет проверка имени и пароля (которые хранятся в файле). Добавление в файл студентов идет через класс Director

```
class Student : User
{   public Student () { }
    public Student(string _name, string _surname, string _password) : base(_name, _surname, _password) { }
    public bool CheckPassword(string n, string s, string p)
    {
        name = n; 
        surname = s; 
        password = p;
       // TextReader tr = new StreamReader("D:\\Students\\Students.txt");
       // String str = "";
      //  str = tr.ReadLine();
      //  foreach()


    }
}
```

Класс Director

```
class Director : User
{
    public Director(string _name, string _surname, string _password) : base(_name, _surname, _password) { }
    public void AddStudent()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Имя:");
        name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Фамилия:");
        surname = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Пароль:");
        password = Console.ReadLine();
        new Student(name, surname, password);
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter("D:\\Students\\Students.txt", true))
        {
            //Добавляем к старому содержимому файла
            writer.WriteLine("Name: {0}\n Surname: {1}\n Password: {2}", name, surname, password);
        }
    }
}
```

Как проверять информацию введенную с консоли с файлом?

Comment: Какую конкретно проверку Вы хотите делать?

Comment: Пользователь вводит имя и пароль. Если эти данные совпадут с базой данных из файла (которые добавлены директором), то пропускает дальше, если нет return 0

Comment: Для начала, хранение пароля в открытом виде в файле уже неправильно. Храните хеши от паролей, для добавления в файл напишите тулзу.

Comment: Если мой ответ был полезен, пожалуйста примите его. [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После ввода данных о студенте, но до создания этого студента и добавления записи в файл надо добавить вызов функции проверки введённых данных:

```
Console.WriteLine("Имя:");
name = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Фамилия:");
surname = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Пароль:");
password = Console.ReadLine();

if (CheckExistingStudent(name, surname, "D:\\Students\\Students.txt")
    return 0;

new Student(name, surname, password);
```

Функция проверки:

```
    private bool CheckExistingStudent(string _name, string _surname, string filePath)
    {
        bool result = false;

        string studentName = "";
        string studentSurname = "";
        StreamReader reader = null;

        try
        {
            reader = new StreamReader(filePath);

            while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                studentName = reader.ReadLine();
                studentSurname = reader.ReadLine();
                reader.ReadLine(); // считываем пароль, но не анализируем его

                studentName = studentName.Substring("Name: ".Length);
                studentSurname = studentSurname.Substring("Surname: ".Length);

                if (studentName == _name && studentSurname == _surname)
                {
                    result = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ошибка при проверке существования студента: {0}", e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (reader != null)
                reader.Close();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Само собой, что данная функция будет работать корректно только при условии соответствия файла со списком студентов тому правилу, которое описано в Вашем исходном сообщении.